# Unity Particles Aren't working with custom script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I started my game dev journey a few weeks ago and I am enjoying it, but sometimes it can get frustrating when things do not work.

I wrote a very basic code for particle system, if we press space then particle should play. The problem is that its not playing, when I hit play it doesn't work for some reason. When I click the particle in the scene then it works and it also works when I check on the play on awake

**The Code**:

```cs
[SerializeField] ParticleSystem engineBoostParticle;
[SerializeField] ParticleSystem sideEngineParticles;

void Start()
{

}

void Update()
{
ThrustingInput();
}

void ThrustingInput()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (!engineBoostParticle.isPlaying)
        {
            engineBoostParticle.Play();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        AS.Stop();
        engineBoostParticle.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Logger.html Make a log message for yourself to check if the Space key event is happening at all.

Comment: Your issue might be that the particle might be played, but on the next iteration of the input loop it will be stopped, so you do not even realize it started. Try to remove the `else` section to see if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check `engineBoostParticle.isEmitting` as well as `isPlaying` in your `if` statement.
It's possible that your system is playing, but not emitting (because the loop is over), so make sure the particle system loops properly as well.

Comment: nope still didnt work can you explain a little bit more i am still confused